# How can I monitor which types of messages are in my Amazon SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, monitoring, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Whenever a queue in Amazon SQS “overflows” I don’t really see any way to debug an issue, since AWS does not seem to provide any kind of monitoring for SQS that lets you segment messages in flight by their payloads - so I have no idea which types of messages are causing an overflow.

*How can I segment messages in Amazon SQS by name/payload/other attributes on a graph, so I can figure out which types of messages I causing the queue to overflow?*

Note: I cannot use a queue-per-message-type approach since I use Elastic Beanstalk and it doesn’t seem to allow having multiple queues per worker (and having a worker per queue is very costly since I usually have lots of message types).

I also log every message type I receive in cloudwatch, but cannot figure out a way to set up a filter/metric that will let me monitor types of messages without having to set up a custom filter for each of them manually.

**UPD:**

I ended up using Cloudwatch Log Insights. It it not ideal since there is no way to [group by task name and plot time-series data at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289784/aggregate-logs-by-field-value-and-plot-as-multiple-series-using-aws-cloudwatch-i/67407330#comment129714466_67407330), but I can at least plot bar graphs of tasks grouped by name and I can then just use filter to specify time frame. Here are some docs on the query format that lets you select virtual fields: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Here's an example of a query that I use to view tasks received by a worker running on [django-eb-sqs-worker](https://github.com/DataGreed/django-eb-sqs-worker) library:

```
fields @message
| parse @message "[*] Received Task(*,*" as hash, taskName, restOfMessage
| display @timestamp, taskName, restOfMessage
| filter ispresent(taskName)
| stats count(*) by taskName
```

Here's a query for filtering finished tasks:

```
fields @message
| parse @message "* Finished Task(*,*. Result: *. Execution time: *s.*" as hash, taskName, restOfMessage1, result, executionTime, additional
| display @timestamp, taskName, result, executionTime, additional
| filter ispresent(taskName)
| stats count(*) by taskName
```

Comment: Can you describe your architecture a bit? SQS allows an unlimited number of messages in a queue so I'm not sure what issue you're running into. Leveraging the beanstalk poller limits your ability to manage things.  Generally you'd have multiple queues and a thread or thread pool to read each one.  That partitions the data more cleanly.  In that way you can determine which type of data is not be handled quickly enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow" here? Note that with FIFO SQS queues you can indicate a message group ID in each message and use this to group/segment messages, but this could affect your ability to process many messages concurrently.

Comment: @jarmod sorry, totally forgot that “overflow” is my custom alarm in cloudwatch that triggers that I have an abnormally large (for my service) number of messages over an extended period of time. Basically it means that either some messages are causing jobs to constnatly fail with an error or (more likely) spawn more jobs leading to a situation when number of messages constantly multiplies. This is a rare situation, but when it arises I have no idea on how to debug it with SQS

Comment: @stdunbar I use Elastic Beanstalk with two environments: web and worker. Messages got pushed into an SQS queue either from web env, or via EB’s cron daemon. Messages have different payloads with the name of a job and parameters for the specified job. Worker receives a message from EB’s SQSD, chooses appropriate job (python function) and executes it with parameters. Some of the jobs can also push messages to the queue. EB doesn’t seem to let me select more than one queue to work with, not sure how to  Work around it easily. Worker is threaded of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd monitor or debug such issues is by either searching though the logs with cloudwatch log insights. You can write a query to count the messages grouped by type and get a histogram over time.

Another way to continously monitor different message types is by using cloudwatch embedded metric format (EMF) for logging. You push a log entry per message and dimension them on message type to be able to view them in cloudwatch metrics and also put alerts on them. However since you mentioned it's mainly for debugging, I'd recommend cloudwatch log insights.

Comment: Is there a way to write a query that would automatically segment log entries by type? E.g. like a regular expression with a varying capture group? Or the only way is to write a query for each of the message types? I have like a hundred of them :)

Comment: I ended up using clodwatch log insights. It it not ideal since there is no way to group by task name and plot time-series data, but I can at least plot bar graphs of tasks grouped by name and I can then just use filter to  specify time frame. Here are some docs on the query format that lets you select virtual fields: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html ; use `count` for plotting graphs and `filter ispresent(fieldname)` to remove empty results

Comment: I've added more details on how I did it to my original question